# Listening to the notification on Android

Tags: android, notifications

I am developing a notification service. For that purpose I just wanted to know that, how to listen for the arrival of notification. I need some tasks to be done when a notification arrives. Also, I am not that much familiar with Android.

Comment: Well, the notification arrives when you send it in code! There you have it.

Comment: there are 100s of answers for this on stack overlow itself....

Comment: I am not sending the notification. I just needed to listen the notifications sent by other applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully once you get familar you will know whats possible and what is not. But as for now, an App can only post notifications on the notification bar. It cannot control or listen to another apps notification. If you really want to fiure out, you will need to open up the HomeScreen code from Android source and see how it works!